# why is this dynamic object getting changed?

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

I have a class named "Human" and have a vector of humans and I populate it this way:

```
humans.push_back(Human());
```

and in another class, I have a vector `human*` pointing to the previous humans in this way:

```
cell.humans.push_back(&humans.back())
```

push_back function creates an object in heap memory and so the object won't change if the stack frames get changed. but apparently, by defining a variable like in a non-related function:

```
string foo = "a";
```

one of the humans' attributes are getting overridden and this is an unexpected behavior.
but when I change the code in a way that the first human vector keeps a pointer of human like this:

```
humans.push_back(new Human())
cell.humans.push_back(humans.back())
```

the issue will be solved. to debug the program, I even used gdb and set a watchpoint on the changed object but gdb got stock in an infinite loop!!!

how can i explain this behavior?

Comment: Show much more code. Your question is not clear enough. Use some smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> push_back function creates an object in heap memory and so the object won't change if the stack frames get changed

Yes, but in this case, that object is just a pointer. Its validity depends on the validity of the object it points to. If the reference to `humans.back()` gets invalidated, then `cell.humans`' pointers be left dangling. De-referencing them would lead to *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 0):

the reason was interesting. when you push back a new object into a vector, the vector class may change the place and copy the previous objects into a new location(after pushing back a new object) but where are keeping the previous pointers that are now free and are invalidated.